Analogy for Probability Problem
This is a follow-up to this question: Conditional probability question.
I'll repeat it here: You purchase a certain product. The manual states that the lifetime $T$ of the product, defined as the amount of time (in years) the product works properly until it breaks down, satisfies $e^{-t/5}$ for all $t\geq 0$. I purchase the product and use it for two years without any problems. What is the probability that it breaks down in the third year?
Now, the way the question is defined, this is really tricky. It really sounds to me like if the product is breaking down in the third year, it didn't break down in the first two years. That is implied. This is accentuated by the use of the word "lifetime".
But the solution says that we need to consider the conditional probability of the machine not breaking in the first two years as well. Is the following analogy a good way to understand this question: if I ask for the probability that a heads is obtained on the third coin toss, I still need to multiply by the probability that the first and second tosses are tails.

The questions of the form "find probability of $E$ knowing $A$" always mean "find $P(E\mid A)$"; they often are hidden, as in your example.

"I still need to multiply by the probability that the first and second tosses are tails"  No.  If talking about the coin, the most common question to ask would have been "What is the probability of getting heads on the third toss given that the first two flips were both tails?"  In such a question we do not multiply by probability of getting first and second as tails in and of itself... we use the definition of conditional probability $\Pr(A\mid B) = \dfrac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$

Only if you were asked that the first head is on the third toss would you have to multiply by the probability that the first two were tails.

Thank you! So the analogy to the original problem is, "You know that the first two tosses are tails. What's the probability that the third toss is heads?"

Hypothetically, suppose that you ignore the offered solution, and try to derive the solution on your own, given the conditional probability formula of $$p(A|B) = \frac{p(A\cap B)}{p(B)}.$$  How would you define the events $~A~$ and $~B~$ to fit the problem's constraints, and what then would the explicit computation of the formula be?
